# Can a business's search for profits be considered as movement in state space?

Tags: optimization, markets, decision-theory

When businesses make decisions to increase profits, they have to adjust several "parameters" of the business such as quantity to output, pricing, choosing a production mix, brand positioning, strategy, and so on.

Can these be approximated to a movement in state space, where a point in state space represented by a certain choice amongst all the possible options? I would also like to know if any prominent economic theorists have viewed things this way.

Comment: Are you acquainted with control theory?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I'm aware of it, but only in a casual way. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Almost anything is a movement in state space.  Can profit-maximisation be seen as hill-climbing? Almost surely. It would be easier If you identified the inputs, outputs and states. Oversimplification is wise